# Rolling SQL Pivot on Rounded Values

Tags: mysql, pivot

I need to do a pretty complicated SQL pivot, and right now I'm unsure how it could possibly be done.

Say I have data that looks like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|     ID     |     UnixTimeStamp     |    Value     |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      0     |     4000685           |      9       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      0     |     4006250           |      2       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      0     |     4012185           |      5       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      0     |     4018385           |      3       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      0     |     4030726           |      7       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      1     |     4000685           |     23       |
```

I would like to pivot in such a way as to have columns are time stamp increments of nearest 6000 and the values are filled in with the value column, and would be rolling. For instance the above data would be transformed to be:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     ID     |   UnixTimeStamp_End   |   0_Col  |  6000_Col  |  12000_Col   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4000685        |   Null   |    Null    |      9       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4006250        |   Null   |     9      |      2       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4012185        |     9    |     2      |      5       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4018385        |     2    |     5      |      3       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4024000        |     5    |     3      |     Null     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      0     |        4030726        |     3    |    Null    |       7      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1     |        4000685        |   Null   |    Null    |      23      |
```

What SQL query could do this?

EDIT: Note that Null was inserted at the 4024000 UnixTimeStamp_End, because there wasn't a Unix time-stamp entry that rounds to 4024000 from the nearest  6000, as there is a ~12000 gap between the 4018385 reading and the 4030726 reading.

Also note that when the ID changes the pivot needs to "reset" as if it has not seen any past values

Comment: do you want to create new table? or you want to execute query to get this result without creating the new table? Yo u can not `INSERT` (4024000) into query result. so to fake it - we need to know where to start?  4000685+6000+... ?but why 402400 then? it should definetely have 5 as last digit.

Comment: the insert could have 5 at the end, as long as it rounds to 4024000

Edit: Also, I don't mind doing inserts on a copy of the original data, but not the original data itself.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, this row doesn't have to be inserted, as long as the next observation (at 4030726) takes into account the placement of the Null value in the 6000_Col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far from perfect. 
It uses extra table with base timestamps.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/645e1c/2

```
SELECT
     res.idx,
     res.period,
     res.UnixTimeStamp,
      CAST(@a := @b AS SIGNED),
      CAST(@b := @c AS SIGNED),
      @c := res.value
FROM 
(SELECT tt.UnixTimeStamp period,
       IF(t1.id IS NULL, 0, t1.id) idx,
       t1.UnixTimeStamp , 
       t1.value
FROM tt
LEFT JOIN t1
ON tt.id = t1.id
   AND t1.UnixTimeStamp >= tt.UnixTimeStamp
   AND t1.UnixTimeStamp < tt.UnixTimeStamp + 6000
ORDER BY tt.id ASC,tt.UnixTimeStamp ASC) res
```

Comment: when I try it with multiple values I think something goes wrong

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/645e1c/1

Comment: thanks, so how would I make it generalizable to any number of columns, say instead of just outputting 0, 6000, 12000, it outputs 0, 6000,12000, ..., 120000

Comment: nvm figured it out